# Сортировка первых 4 и последних 4 элементов массива С++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Нужно в  динамическом массиве  отсортировать первые 4 элемента по возрастанию, а последние 4 по убыванию.

Написал так:

```
for (c = 0; c < N; c++)//колличество проходов 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {

                if (arr[i+1] < arr[i])
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                    arr[i+1] = temp;
                }
        }

    for (int j = N; j >N-4; j--)
    {

        if (arr[j - 1] < arr[j])
        {
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            arr[j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

В visual studio вроде все работает(хотя до этого похожие глюки были), а в CodeBlocks почему то на 4м элементе с конца обсирается, и выводит вместо элемента какое то странное число.
[Скрин](http://prntscr.com/h9za1e)

Почему так получается, и как мне это исправить?

Comment: А мне вот кажется, вы не понимаете, что индексация массива идет с нуля. И если в массиве N элементов, обращение к arr[N] - уже выход за границы массива...

Comment: ваш алгоритм вообще не похож на сортировку, прогоните например '2,3,1,4' через вашу часть по возрастанию. думаю на выходе получите 2,1,3,4

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , *facepalm*.... точно, Спасибо :D)

Comment: @MrStacky отладчик осваивайте :-)

Comment: Еще есть `std::sort` который умеет сортировать и по возрастанию, и по убыванию, и вообще как угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать std::sort, то можно так:

```
    const size_t count = 10;
    int arr[count];
    // ...Заполнение arr данными...
    std::sort(arr, arr + 4);
    std::sort(arr + count - 4, arr + count, std::greater<int>());
```

Более полную версию этого кода можно глянуть [здесь](https://ideone.com/ZJ0Cwo).